# How to calculate normal vector of a Bézier curve?

Tags: mathematics, linear-algebra, beziers

How I can calculate the normal vector for two dimensional Bézier curve?

(I have the control points of the curve in the x y plane)

Answer (score 3):

If vector `(x,y)` is a tangent vector of your curve, then the normal vector is simply `(y,-x)`. So you just need to find a tangent vector, and it all depends on how exactly you define the curve.

If your curve comes from a **parametric representation** `p(t) = (x(t),y(t))` which is sufficiently continuous, then a good approximation of the tangent vector at `t` is, given a very small `ɛ`:

```
       p(t+ɛ)-p(t)
v(t) = ———————————
             ɛ

         x(t+ɛ)-x(t)   y(t+ɛ)-y(t)
v(t) = ( ——————————— , ——————————— )
              ɛ             ɛ
```

This applies to *e.g.* Bézier curves.

If your curve comes from a **dense list of points** then a good approximation comes from taking the two closest points on the curve, `p0` and `p1`, and then your tangent is:

```
v(t) = (p1 - p0) / distance(p1, p0)
```

If your curve comes from a **scattered list of points** then the above method will probably exhibit too many discontinuities, but so will your curve unless you use some kind of interpolation. What I suggest is consider the interpolation function (for instance, cubic interpoltion) as a parametric function, and apply the first method.

Comment: thank you for answer me. please can you clarify the above equations(related with Bezier curves) with a simple example  using actual numbers? I don't understand what t,ɛ meant and how calculated . @Sam Hocevar

Comment: can you show us how you are getting the points on the curve? Is it a cubic bezier? Quadratic? It it 2d or 1d (explicit)?